# What is the easiest way to hide hamburger menu image after width-max: 480px using media query?

Tags: html, css

My hamburger menu won't appear in a responsive layout using a media query.

It only appears if I add it to my main CSS  which defeats the purpose of the hamburger menu - to appear only when my viewport is 480px or less in width.

```
<nav class="navbar">

        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CASINO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">HOTEL</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ENTERTAINMENT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">MEMBERS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JOIN</a></li>
        </ul>

      </nav>

      <img class="burger-nav" src="./images/burger-nav.png" />

/* .burger-nav{
  position: absolute;
  left: 95%;
  top: 16px;
} */
```

When I comment out the above css, the hamburger image doesn't appear even when I later add it to my media query.

I even set the main body class ".burger-nav" containing the image to display as none to later add it to my media query.

```
.burger-nav{
  display: none;
}
```

This is my media query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .burger-nav{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 95%;
    top: 16px;
  }
}
```

How can I get my hamburger menu image to only appear when the width of a viewport is 480px or less.

Comment: I would like to help you, but I spent time already on another question and you never even replied? This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63795307 // Was my code snippet helpful, or do you need more explanations in implementing it? Cheers

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown us. Please create a [MRE] so we can see the problem you are having and be able to help.

Comment: If you check out my github link to my website, the burger nav image doesn't show regardless if it's added to my media query: https://derrickogole.github.io/atlantic-casino/ @FluffyKitten

Comment: Can you have a look at my github link to my website? If you look at my media query and in main css code (same code as above, the responsive image of hamburger nav at 480px or less should work fine) but it doesn't: https://derrickogole.github.io/atlantic-casino/  @LaurentC

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works :) The question itself must include the minimum amount of the relevant code required to show the problem. External links can change or break over time, so once you fix your site the problem can't be seen any more and the question no longer has any value to other users. Please see how to create a [MRE]

Comment: Sorry. I should be more specific. The issue is on a mobile phone layout at 480px or less, the hamburger menu doesn't show. This is the code for the hamburger menu:

In html, directly underneath my navigation menu. 

</nav>
      <img class="burger-nav" src="./images/burger-nav.png" />

My css:

.burger-nav{
  display: none;
}

Media Query:

/* Media Query */

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .burger-nav{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 95%;
    top: 16px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
  }
}

Comment: @FluffyKitten The problem is the image doesn't show at 480px or less. I have made a codepen for it where it works but it doesn't work on my page: https://codepen.io/derrickogole/pen/MWyVVbq Is there a problem with my background color or alignment of text in my navigation bar: